# Lock keyring and umount ~/Private on lock screen

Tags: gnome, suspend, password, lock-screen, ecryptfs

My Ubuntu-mate 18.04  has quite convenient lock screen. I would like to lock my gnome-keyring and unmount ~/Private (ecryptfs partition) while screen is locked. 
The idea is to get a protection against "cold boot" in case computer gets stolen while in locked/suspend state.

So far I have made a script that monitors screensaver to lock/unmount

```
#!/bin/bash
    dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.mate.ScreenSaver'" |
      while read x; do
        case "$x" in 
          *"boolean true"*) 
              echo SCREEN_LOCKED, umounting private
              ecryptfs-umount-private
              kill -9 $(pgrep gnome-keyring-d)
              kill -9 $(pgrep ssh-agent)
              ;;
          *"boolean false"*) echo SCREEN_UNLOCKED;;  
        esac
      done
```

and a simple shell script that enables them back

```
#!/bin/bash
# Read Password
echo -n Password for keyring: 
read -s password
echo
# Run Command

echo -n $password | gnome-keyring-daemon -r --unlock  --components=secrets,ssh
#--components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh

if mount |grep /home/kouzne/Private >/dev/null; then
  echo /home/kouzne/Private already mounted!
else
  printf "%s" "$password" | ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring
  /sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private
fi
```

It works somewhat, but I need to run the unlock script manually, and sometimes keyring ends-up in unresponsive position (with 100% cpu usage by gnome-keyring-d).

Is there any way to feed the password I enter to unlock the screen to external programs and/or add custom hooks to screen lock-unlock?

Also any hint on possible reason for gnome-keyring-d misbehaving would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599749/why-is-the-gnome-keyring-not-locked-when-the-screen-is-locked